# Crear procedimiento almacenado de inserción de la tabla 1 a la tabla 2, con el id retornado de la tabla 1 en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi duda es como crear un procedimiento almacenado en el cual me permita crear una inserción de una tabla 1, a su ves retornar el id, para ser insertado en la tabla 2 y que todo esto se encuentre en un procedimiento almacenado. De ante mano agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Hola, ¿Ambas tablas tienen campos id con propiedad **Autoincrement**?

Comment: Ambas tablas tienen su id autoincrementable , nos tante la tabla 2 necesita el id de la tabla 1 para su inserción que se genero al crear la inserción

Comment: Eso lo entiendo claramente, pero ¿el Id tiene la propiedad **Autoincrement**?, o ¿el campo id es llenado manualmente?

Comment: En efecto los id de cada tabla son autoincrement

Comment: Publico la respuesta, a la espera de alguna duda para poder responderla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero creamos las tablas, en este caso le agrego integridad referencial con **FOREIGN KEY**

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA1
(
    ID_TABLA1 INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE TABLA2
(
    ID_TABLA2 INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ID_TABLA1 INT NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(100)
)

ALTER TABLE TABLA2 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TABLA2_VS_TABLA1 FOREIGN KEY (ID_TABLA1) REFERENCES TABLA1(ID_TABLA1)
GO
```

Luego creamos el procedimiento que cuenta con un parametro **output** que nos devuelve el valor del **id_tabla1** con **SCOPE_IDENTITY()**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_INSERT_TABLA1
    @NOMBRE VARCHAR(100),
    @ID_TABLA1 INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLA1 VALUES (@NOMBRE)
    SET @ID_TABLA1 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
```

Realizamos la prueba de ejecución del procedimiento, obtenemos el id_tabla1 devuelto e insertamos la tabla2

```
DECLARE @ID_TABLA1 INT
EXEC USP_INSERT_TABLA1 'HOLA MUNDO', @ID_TABLA1 OUTPUT

INSERT TABLA2 VALUES (@ID_TABLA1, 'ESTO SE TABLA 2 GUARDA EL ID DE TABLA1')
```

Consultamos los resultados

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA1
SELECT * FROM TABLA2
```

---

Respondiendo a lo consultado, puedes hacer todo en el procedimiento del siguiente modo.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_INSERT_TABLAS
    @NOMBRE VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLA1 VALUES (@NOMBRE)
    DECLARE @ID_TABLA1 INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    INSERT INTO TABLA2 VALUES (@ID_TABLA1, @NOMBRE)
END
GO
```

Y ejecutamos el procedimiento del siguiente modo, note que ahora no sería necesario retornar el id como **OUTPUT**.

```
EXEC USP_INSERT_TABLAS 'HOLA MUNDO'
```

Comment: Una consulta, si comprendo bien crea un procedimiento  almacenado el cual le devuelve el id y luego usted realiza la inserción en la segunda tabla. Perfecto me parece. Pero hay alguna manera que en el mismo procedimiento de  USP_INSERT_TABLA1 se realice todo a la vez. A eso me refiero que en el mismo. A la hora de ejecutarlo se cree la inserción de la tabla 1 guarde la variable del id que se inserto y luego lo inserte en la segunda tabla. De ante mano disculpe la molestia

Comment: Acabo de agrega la duda indicada al final de la respuesta propuesta, si es la respuesta correcta a tu pregunta por favor marcar como **respuesta correcta** para poder ayudar a aquellas personas que tengan la misma duda.

Comment: Se lo agradezco demasiado. Muchas gracias